# Создание файлов на сервере через FTP

Tags: c#, ftp

Вопрос казался простым но найти полного ответа так и не удалось. Можно ли  создать .txt файл на сервере через FTP и потом дополнять его? Именно создать а не загрузить ранее созданный на локальном диске. И именно дополнять строками а не перезаписывать затирая старые?

Попробовал создать файл вот так :

```
byte[] data = { 0 };
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://.com/");
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.AppendFile;
Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
requestStream.Close();
```

Падает ошибка -

> Запрашиваемый URI-адрес недопустим для этой команды FTP.

Разве такое может быть если File Zilla нормально создает файлы ?

Comment: Может File Zilla смотрит есть ли файл, и если нет, то создает, а если есть - использует `AppendFile`? В конце FTP uri в вас есть имя файла?

Comment: @pavel1787mego на самом деле не очень хорошая, видимо в этом и была ошибка.

Comment: @pavel1787mego и то тоже )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, можно, команда протокола [APPE](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/RawFTP.htm#APPE)

Comment: Вы хоть читайте что скидываете "Append data to the end of a file on the remote host." Файла нет, его сначала нужно создать.

Comment: Извиняюсь, прочитал внимательней. что APPE создает или дополняет файл

Answer (score 1):

Благодаря уважаемым `Lunar` и `pavel1787mego` пришел вот к такому простецкому решению. APPE - создает файл если его нет и дополняет его данными если уже создан. Благодарю за подсказки!

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        string data = "22222";
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Username", "password");
        client.UploadString("ftp://patch" + FILENAME + ".txt", "APPE", data);
        Console.ReadKey();
     }
```